# Socket ReceiveTimeout on Linux

Tags: linux, sockets, boost-asio

I am writing a synchronous client. Part of it is a `Connection` object which is responsible for the actual sending and receiving of the data. The entire library is written using the Boost ASIO `ip::tcp::socket` class.

I have a test in which the client calls a method on the server (which sleeps for 2 seconds) with a timeout of 1 second. My code has detected that execution took more than the requested time, but it didn't return in time. Instead, it returned after the 2 whole seconds.

I have narrowed down the problem to the `receive` method:

```
void Connection::receive(const mutable_buffers_1& buffers, const DurationType& timeout)
{
    // to make sure it isn't 0 by mistake
    auto actualTimeout = std::max(DurationType(milliseconds(1)), timeout);
    SocketReceiveTimeoutOption timeoutOption(actualTimeout);
    error_code ec;
    _socket.set_option(timeoutOption, ec);
    RPC_LOG(TRACE) << "Setting timeout " << actualTimeout << " returned: " << ec.message();
    RPC_LOG(TRACE) << "Receiving...";
    if (_socket.receive(buffers, MSG_WAITALL, ec) != buffer_size(buffers))
    {
        throw RpcCommunicationError("Did not receive the expected number of bytes from connection");
    }
    RPC_LOG(TRACE) << "Received! With error code: " << ec.message();
}
```

`DurationType` is just a convenience typedef:

```
typedef boost::chrono::system_clock ClockType;
typedef ClockType::time_point::duration DurationType;
```

`SocketReceiveTimeoutOption` is an option implemented for sockets:

```
template <int Name>
class SocketTimeoutOption
{
public:
    #ifdef BSII_WINDOWS
    SocketTimeoutOption(const DurationType& timeout) : _value(static_cast<DWORD>(boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds>(timeout).count())) {}
    #else
    SocketTimeoutOption(const DurationType& timeout) : _value(Utils::toTimeval(timeout)) {}
    #endif

    // Get the level of the socket option.
    template <typename Protocol>
    int level(const Protocol&) const
    {
        return SOL_SOCKET;
    }

    // Get the name of the socket option.
    template <typename Protocol>
    int name(const Protocol&) const
    {
        return Name;
    }

    // Get the address of the timeout data.
    template <typename Protocol>
    void* data(const Protocol&)
    {
        return &_value;
    }

    // Get the address of the timeout data.
    template <typename Protocol>
    const void* data(const Protocol&) const
    {
        return &_value;
    }

    // Get the size of the boolean data.
    template <typename Protocol>
    std::size_t size(const Protocol&) const
    {
        return sizeof(_value);
    }

private:
    #ifdef BSII_WINDOWS
    DWORD _value;
    #else
    timeval _value;
    #endif
};

typedef SocketTimeoutOption<SO_RCVTIMEO> SocketReceiveTimeoutOption;
typedef SocketTimeoutOption<SO_SNDTIMEO> SocketSendTimeoutOption;
```

And finally

```
namespace Utils
{
    inline
        timeval toTimeval(const DurationType& duration)
    {
            timeval val;
            auto seconds = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::seconds>(duration); // TODO: make sure this is truncated down in case there's fractional seconds
            val.tv_sec = static_cast<long>(seconds.count());

            auto micro = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::microseconds>(duration - seconds);
            val.tv_usec = static_cast<long>(micro.count());

            return val;
    }
}
```

The problem is that even though I specify a 1s timeout, the `receive` method still takes the entire 2 seconds. Here's the log:

> 2014-09-14 10:27:53.348383 | trace | 0x007f24e50ae7c0 | Setting timeout 999917107 nanoseconds returned: Success
>   2014-09-14 10:27:53.348422 | trace | 0x007f24e50ae7c0 | Receiving...
>   2014-09-14 10:27:55.349152 | trace | 0x007f24e50ae7c0 | Received! With error code: Success

As you can see, setting the timeout worked, but still the `receive` method took 2 seconds.

The same code works just fine on Windows.

Comment: `DurationType` and `SocketReceiveTimeoutOption` are not defined. If they are typedefs to actual boost types, please show the typedefs or use actual boost types in your example.

Comment: Thanks. Edited original question. Now I see it's possible that I have a bug in setting the timeout option in the Linux case. I will check and update.

Comment: Update: I think that the duration conversion to timeval is OK. I added some logging and got the following: 
Converting 999718938 nanoseconds to timeval 
Got: 0 seconds + 999718 useconds

Answer (score 0):

[`socket::receive()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/receive/overload1.html) will block until either:

- One or more bytes of data has been received successfully
- An error occurs that would prevent data from being received

For blocking synchronous operations, if the underlying OS operation returns with a non-critical error, such as one indicating that the operation would block or should be tried again, then Boost.Asio will block in [`poll()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/poll.html) waiting for the file descriptor to become ready.  The blocking call to `poll()` is not affected by the `SO_RCVTIMEO` socket option.  Once the file descriptor is ready, Boost.Asio will reattempt the operation.

Thus, the scenario in the original question occurs as follows:

```
Time | Client                                 | Server
-----+----------------------------------------+-------------------------------
     | socket.connect(...);                   | acceptor.accept(...);
0.00 | socket.set_option(timeout(second(1))); | sleep(seconds(2));
0.01 | socket.receive(...);                   | 
0.02 | |-- recv(...);                         |  
1.02 | | // timeout, errno = EAGAIN           | 
1.03 | |-- poll(socket);                      | 
2.00 | | // data available, poll unblocks     | socket.write(...);
2.01 | `-- recv(...);// success               |
```

To get the desired timeout behavior, either:

- Use the pattern presented in the official Boost.Asio [timeout examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.timeouts).
- Invoke the OS call directly.  However, be cautious, as other operations may indirectly affect this approach.  For example, if an asynchronous operation is initiated on the socket, then the socket will be set to non-blocking.  This will cause the `recv()` function to return immediately on a non-blocking socket regardless of the `SO_RCVTIMEO` socket option.